# Jsoup nested values inside list item

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an HTML page that I'm trying to dig out the `Logname` value from. I can get all the `li` text jammed together as one string, but not quite what I want. I'd like just the second part of the `li` Logname after the `</span>`. Any way to easily get that?  With what I have, I could do a split and get what I want but seems like there should be a more elegant way?

Current code

```
Elements detail = mHtml.select ("div.alpha-first");


        for (Element items : detail)
        {
            Log.d (TAG, " label text " + items.text());

            detail.

            if (items.text().equals ("ACID"))
            {
                Log.d (TAG, " got ACID ");
            }

        }
```

HTML

```
<html>
<title>emp id chart</title>
<body>
<div class="alpha-first">
      <ul class="account-detail">
         <li><span class="label">ID</span>42</li>
         <li><span class="label">Logname</span>George</li>
         <li><span class="label">Surname</span>Glass</li>
         <li><span class="label">ACID</span>15</li>
         <li><span class="label">Dept</span>101348</li>
         <li><span class="label">Empclass</span>Echo</li>
      </ul>
      <p class="last-swipe">3 Apr 9:53</p><br>  </div>
   <div class="detail-last-loc">
      <p style="font-size: 8pt;">Current status</p>
      <p class="current-location">Bldg #23 South Lot</p>
      <p> current time 10:43 <br /></p>
      <div class="detail-extra">
         <p><a href="/empswipe/history/151034842">More</a> | <a href="/empswipe/history/151034842/3">3 Day History</a></p>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood, given your example, you would want to obtain from: `<li><span class="label">Logname</span>George</li>`, the value: `George`.

You really don't need to iterate, you can get it directly. I would not go so far as to call this code elegant, but still, here it is:

```
    //Select the <span> element the text "Logname"
    Elements select = mHtml.select(".account-detail span.label:contains(Logname)");

    //Get the element itself, since the select returns a list
    Element lognameSpan = select.get(0);

    //Get the <li> parent of the <span>
    Element parent = lognameSpan.parent();

    //Access the text node of the <li> directly since there is only one
    String logname = parent.textNodes().get(0).text();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was wanting to do. My example code was a a little confusing as I was branching on ACID rather than Logname.